# Updating Ubuntu to the latest

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I've been using Ubuntu for quite some time now and I absolutely love it.
I recently purchased a laptop (Dell Inspiron 15r 5521) which is supported by Ubuntu (I checked in the certified hardware list). 
It comes with Windows 8 pre installed. I followed a guide here that shows how to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 with doing something in BIOS and boot repair and stuff. It worked well and I successfully dual booted them.

Now my question is.
I have no clue about the UEFI thing. If I want to update Ubuntu to 13.04, will it mess up the laptop? I'm asking cause installing it was a lenghty procedure. Will updating have any special needs or steps to be followed or is it just a normal update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take it easy, Ubuntu has no way to mess up your laptop, if you install it with a little bit of attention. This page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI have everything that you need to installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: You're mostly correct when it comes to causing *hardware* problems, but upgrades always pose a risk to software and data. Note that the well-known Samsung EFI bug is the latest exception to the hardware rule; if that crops up, it can require a hardware exchange. Of course, Raghav is using a Dell, so Samsung's bug isn't likely to crop up in this case; but the principle still holds....

Answer (score 0):

Installing or upgrading an OS ***always*** poses some risk of causing problems. Bugs, hardware failures, subtle inconsistencies or problems in the existing installation, and so on can all combine with an update to create a huge headache. That said, such problems are rare.

Just to be sure, back up your important user data -- the worst cases I've heard of involve people accidentally trashing their irreplaceable user data during the upgrade.